# MS-Access - select part of a string from email file

Tags: ms-access

I have set up a student database in ms-access 2016 to track students on support to study and imported all the emails from a folder related to students into a database called emails (I still need to work out the VBA code to update this folder on opening/closing a form). When a student emails me, I can match that email easily to the main database as it is just from them. However, when an email is sent to a student, often other staff members are cc'd in to the email. I therefore need to be able to select out just the student's email name from the To column. So it may be Jo Smith; Leah Jones; Jo Davies (UG) (or any combination of that depending on if the student is the main recipient or not. The name of the student will always have (UG) at the end of the name, so can be identified.

Is there a way of selecting out just the student name (with the (UG) at the end is fine) from the string of names into a new column using an update column? The recipient names are separated by a ; (but if the student is first or last on the list obviously won't have a ' before/after their name). I need this to link it to the name so I can see emails sent to and from the student in forms, alongside their other information.

Many thanks in advance
Ali

Comment: Probably best solved with a UDF in VBA. Split the names to an array, loop through the names in the array until you find the one containing the `(UG)` and return it.

Comment: Thank you - my VBA is still pretty basic (email a student direct from forms, save on close so far) so not sure how I would go about that. Would you have an example to hand at all (sorry I know it is cheeky to ask).

Comment: I gave it a shot. Like I mentioned it's been forever since I wrote one of these or really any VBA at all. I think the syntax and logic is correct, but I'm on a mac at the moment and can't test.

Answer (score 0):

It's been over a decade since I wrote an Access VBA UDF and probably a year or 5 since I wrote VBA, so grain of salt here, but this should be in the ballpark:

```
Function getStudentEmail(emails as String) as String

    'Declare array to hold emails
    Dim emailsArr() as String

    'Split delimited string of emails into the array with split() function
    emailsArr = Split(emails, ";")
    
    'Loop through array
    For Each email in EmailsArr
        'Check if email string has (UG) in it
        If InStr(1, email, "(UG)", 1) Then
            'Set the return to the email and break the for loop ending the function
            getStudentEmail = email
            Exit For
        End If
    Next email

End Function
```

How to use:

1. Open up the Visual Basic Editor (VBE) with the "Visual Basic" button in the ribbon under the "Database Tools" section:

   [image]
2. Right-click on your database in the "project" pane and choose Insert>>Module:

   [image]
3. Paste your code in:

   [image]
4. Now you should be able to use this function in your SQL like `SELECT getStudentEmail(yourEmailColumn) FROM yourtable;`

Comment: thank you - sorry being really dumb here - where abouts would I put this code? Can I run it in the Email Table column that will have the new email value, or straight into the form? Sorry, you are being really helpful and I am having a brain block (give me MS sql or R any day, as my access is also really basic and rusty, but neither seemed to have the form feed I needed)

Comment: Oh yeah. That's definitely a tricky part if you haven't done this before. I updated the answer with instructions on how to use this code in your SQL. Also, since I was in a spare windows machine to get the screenshots, I tested the code too. I made one small change, and it works just like you are wanting.

Comment: Aww thank you so much. Perfect. Thank you for taking the time to answer